# In Orchard CMS, how do I customize the Blog widget?

Tags: orchardcms

I'm still new to Orchard and don't quite understand how it fits together.

The home page shows a blog post list, which is what I want. Except that right on top of the list is a *summary* of the blog. I only want the blog entries to show and not the general blog summary/header.

How do I customize the Blog widgets(?) to not show the summary/header?

I am using a custom derivative of the "TheThemeMachine" theme.

Comment: mmh, looks very much like a programming / software development related question to me. This specific question is answered by writing a placement file that will send the blog summary and header parts to the "-" zone (i.e. oblivion). You can discover what shapes you need to move using the Shape Tracing feature from the Designer Tools module.

Comment: @bertrand true, voted to reopen.

Comment: Same question here--it's sad that I'm a programmer here with the same *programming* question and it is closed.  I find more closed questions than open any more.  Very sad.